# question about harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've made an erroneous assumption about the solution, but don't know what's wrong.

Take the harmonic oscillator equation:

$m\ddot{x}(t)+kx(t)=F(t)$

when $F(t)$ is $F_0\sin(wt)$, I know that the position $x(t)$ will be $A\sin(wt+\theta)$. But if i put it in equation and try to isolate amplitude $A$, i will get:

$-mw^2A\sin(wt+\theta)+kA\sin(wt+\theta)=F_0\sin(wt)$

$A=\dfrac{F_0\sin(wt)}{(k-mw^2)\sin(wt+\theta)}$

which will not be a constant for any phase $\theta$ different than zero, and will diverge when $wt+\theta \rightarrow 0$.

My formation is not in mathematics, so please point if I've made some basic mistake/wrong assumption.

Comment: "I know that the position $x(t)$ will be $A\sin(wt+\theta)$". There's your mistake.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the ansatz @spaceisdarkgreen.

Comment: It turns out that there will be a nonzero phase when there is a resistance term, that is if you have an $\dot{x}$ term.

Comment: @Tucker ahh you're right for a steady state

Answer (score 3):

You need to use $\sin(wt+\theta)=\sin(wt)\cos\theta+\cos(wt)\sin\theta$.  Inserting this gives
$$
(-mw^2+k)A(\sin(wt)\cos\theta +\cos(wt)\sin\theta)=F_0\sin(wt)
$$
This must hold for all $t$ so choose $t=0$ to produce
$$
(-mw^2+k)A\sin\theta=0
$$
from which you deduce $\theta=0$ or $k/m=w^2$.  Assuming the first
gives 
$$
A=\frac{F_0}{k-mw^2}\, .
$$
You can explore other choices at your own leisure.

Comment: $k/m = w^2$ will most likely not be an option. The physical parameters of the oscillator $k,m$ may be such that they agree with the frequency of the driving term.

Comment: @Tucker The case $k/m=w^2$ is a little delicate as the frequency of the driving force $F$ is resonant with the natural frequency of the unforced system.  Thus the singularity in the amplitude is not unexpected.  In a physical system there would be some damping which would add a term linear in $\dot{x}$ in the ODE and would remove the singularity in the denominator.

Comment: I agree, that is why I suggested that $k/m = w^2$ wasn't really an option.